# sql query to join two tables and a boolean flag to indicate whether it contains any words from third table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, amazon-redshift

I have 3 tables with the following schema

```
create table main (
  main_id int PRIMARY KEY,
  secondary_id int NOT NULL
);

create table secondary (
  secondary_id int NOT NULL,
  tags varchar(100)
);

create table bad_words (
  words varchar(100) NOT NULL
);

insert into main values (1, 1001);
insert into main values (2, 1002);
insert into main values (3, 1003);
insert into main values (4, 1004);

insert into secondary values (1001, 'good word');
insert into secondary values (1002, 'bad word');
insert into secondary values (1002, 'good word');
insert into secondary values (1002, 'other word');
insert into secondary values (1003, 'ugly');
insert into secondary values (1003, 'bad word');
insert into secondary values (1004, 'pleasant');
insert into secondary values (1004, 'nice');

insert into bad_words values ('bad word');
insert into bad_words values ('ugly');
insert into bad_words values ('worst');

expected output
----------------
1, 1000, good word, 0 (boolean flag indicating whether the tags contain any one of the  words from the bad_words table)
2, 1001, bad word,good word,other word , 1
3, 1002, ugly,bad word, 1
4, 1003, pleasant,nice, 0
```

I am trying to use case to select 1 or 0 for the last column and use a join to join the main and secondary table, but getting confused and stuck. Can someone please help me with a query ? These tables are stored in redshift and i want query compatible with redshift.

you can use the above schema to try your query in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)

EDIT: I have updated the schema and expected output now by removing the `PRIMARY KEY` in secondary table so that easier to join with the bad_words table.

Comment: What is the datatype of tags?

Comment: I updated the question with a schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.main_id, m.secondary_id, t.tags, t.is_bad_word
FROM srini.main m
JOIN (
    SELECT st.secondary_id, st.tags, exists (select 1 from srini.bad_words b where st.tags like '%'+b.words+'%') is_bad_word
    FROM 
    ( SELECT secondary_id, LISTAGG(tags, ',') as tags
      FROM srini.secondary
      GROUP BY secondary_id ) st
) t on t.secondary_id = m.secondary_id;
```

This worked for me in redshift and produced the following output with the above mentioned schema.

```
1   1001    good word   false
3   1003    ugly,bad word   true
2   1002    good word,other word,bad word   true
4   1004    pleasant,nice   false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use EXISTS and a regex comparison with \m and \M (markers for beginning and end of a word, respectively):

```
with
  main(main_id, secondary_id) as (values (1, 1000), (2, 1001),  (3, 1002), (4, 1003)),
  secondary(secondary_id, tags) as (values (1000, 'very good words'), (1001, 'good and bad words'), (1002, 'ugly'),(1003, 'pleasant')),
  bad_words(words) as (values ('bad'), ('ugly'), ('worst'))

select *, exists (select 1 from bad_words where s.tags ~* ('\m'||words||'\M'))::int as flag
from main m
join secondary s using (secondary_id)
```

Comment: I tried your query (and a few smaller variations) in sqlfiddle and it didnt work. where can i try your query?

Comment: thanks, it works in sqlfiddle now. But unfortunately it fails when i execute it in redshift with `ERROR: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error`. you can read more this [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_correlated_subqueries.html). also [redshift docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/pattern-matching-conditions.html) says LIKE is better than regex.

Comment: I have updated the question with a slightly modified schema now, can you please take a look now ?

Comment: @srini in the examples of redshift docs it states that backslashes should be doubled, but it doesn't explicitly document \m and \M, nor \y. Try doubling the backslashes (`~* '\\m'||words||'\\M'`), and if that doesn't work try replacing both \m and \M with \y, and alternatively with [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] respectively. These all work with PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`select main_id, a.secondary_id, tags, case when c.words is not null then 1 else 0 end 
from main a
join secondary b on b.secondary_id = a.secondary_id
left outer join bad_words c on c.words like b.tags`

Comment: I am looking for substring matches of words in tags. your query returned `2, 1001, good and bad words, 0`